# Mysql select query count until reach the condition

Tags: mysql, count, conditional-statements, limit

I have lists of users with his points and game id. I need to find the rank of the specified user based on the game order by the maximum lb_point. Below is my table.

```
lb_id    user_id   game_id   room_id   lb_point
------------------------------------------------
1         1        2         1         670     
2         1        1         2         200     
3         1        2         2         650     
4         1        1         1         400     
5         3        2         1         700     
6         4        2         5         450     
7         2        1         3         550     
8         2        1         1         100     
9         1        1         1         200
```

I have already done this by using PHP code and its working fine as follows.

```
$game_id = 2;
$user_id = 1;
$query_rnk = $this->db->query('SELECT user_id AS uid FROM leader_board WHERE game_id = "'.$game_id.'" GROUP by user_id ORDER BY lb_point DESC');
        if ($query_rnk->num_rows() > 0){
            $j=1;
            foreach($query_rnk->result() as $row_rnk){
                if($row_rnk->uid == $user_id){
                    $rnk_status = 1;
                    break;
                }
            $j++;
            }
            if($rnk_status == 1){
                $resp['rank'] = $j;
            }
        }
```

Answer is: 2.

But i need to find this by using one query. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe some explanation about what this code is doing will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do with a select  counting the number of rows of a proper select

```
select count(*) 
from (
      select distinct user_id
      from leader_board 
      where   lb_point >= (select  max( lb_point )
             from leader_board 
             where user_id = 1   
             and game_id = 2 )
      and game_id = 2
) t
```

Comment: getting error " #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row  "

Comment: I have update thge answer  .. (you don't cjeck for room_id ?)

Comment: Let me check. I don't check the room_id. This is for some other reference.

Comment: But if i use the user_id = 4, then my answer should be 3. But i am getting 4. Because the user_id we need use "GROUP BY".

Comment: have you change the user_id in the query  (or assigned to a var)?

Comment: I changed like this. " select count(*) 
from (
      select *
      from leader_board 
      where   lb_point >= (select  max( lb_point )
             from leader_board 
             where user_id = 4   
             and game_id = 2)
) t
where game_id = 2 "

Comment: I have changed the answer ( i haven't see that user_id 1 has more then a rows)

Comment: Now i am getting error " #1054 - Unknown column 'game_id' in 'where clause'  " Can you please check

Comment: I have update the answer  .. filtering properly for game_id .. let me know

Comment: Awesome, it works. You saved me. Thanks you so much :)

Comment: I have to do another condition. Now i need to find the same based on the user_id who got more points in all games. So i need to add the highest points all game_id to do this. Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117289/discussion-between-naren-and-scaisedge).

Comment: The better choice is  a new  post with a properly  explained  question .. eventually comment me .. if i'not busy .. i take a look

Comment: Hi. I added in new question. Can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476916/mysql-select-query-count-until-reach-the-condition-with-condition

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the rank of `user_id = 1`, try this:

```
SELECT urank
FROM (
    SELECT user_id AS uid, @rank := @rand + 1 AS urank
    FROM leader_board
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) t
    WHERE game_id = '$game_id'
    GROUP by user_id
    ORDER BY lb_point DESC
) tmp
WHERE uid = '$user_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*)+1 as Rank from (select lb_point from games where game_id =2 order by lb_point DESC) as list where list.lb_point > (select max(lb_point) from games where user_id = 1 and game_id = 2)
```

This will give the rank 2 for user_id = 1 in game_id = 2 which is the answer you've mentioned in question.